# how to add the original-title in <a >tag using php?

Tags: php

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-align:center; color:#000; font:bold 14px/39px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" rel="tipsyN" class="iWidget 
                    <?php if($get_status=="book") 
                          {
                            echo "booked";
                            echo 'original-title=Booked';
                          } 
                         if($get_status=="advance")
                          { 
                            echo "advanced";
                            echo "original-title=advanced";
                          } 

                   ?>" >

                </a>
```

Kindly help me to set the **Original-title** from my above code.
I want to displaythe title**booked** and assign the corresponding class **booked** if the above condition is true,else next condition will be executed with the same format i said.

Comment: I don't really understand, what are you trying to achieve here. Please clarify.

Comment: And what's the problem ? Obviously there are missing quotes, but you should see it in the output yourself.

Comment: What is original-title ? Certainly it is not a valid html attribute.

Comment: ya i found my mistake..

Comment: i got the correct output in right format

Comment: then how should i call it @Lorenz Meyer ji?

Comment: @kiruthiga Tell first what it is. If you need a custom attribute in HTML use the data- prefix, like data-original-title.

Comment: "original-title" is same as what you said,but data-* attributes are used as a storage area for private data

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="text-align:center; color:#000; font:bold 14px/39px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" rel="tipsyN" class="iWidget 
                    <?php if($get_status=="book") 
                          {
                            echo "booked";
                          } 
                         if($get_status=="advance")
                          { 
                            echo "advanced";
                          } 

                   ?>"
                   <?php
                    if($get_status=="book") 
                      {
                        echo 'original-title="Booked"';
                      }
                   if($get_status=="advance")
                   {
                    echo 'original-title="advanced"';

                   }

                   ?>

                    >
```

if anything better than this code,kindly guide it for my improvement.